# Firebase - Detect if a certain user already signed in

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Let's say I already have ID of other user. Can I somehow detect if that user already signed in or not ?
I need that function because I'm developing a web app with board, where only online team members are displayed.

I searched the Firebase documentation and there is only function to check if I currently sign in :

```
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

if (user) {
  // User is signed in.
} else {
  // No user is signed in.
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase Authentication doesn't have a sense of whether or not your app is actively being used by some user.  The check you're performing now just tells you if the user has previously signed in to your app.

If you want to maintain user presence, Firebase Realtime Database can help you with that.  There is a lengthy description of a solution [described in the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/presence).

Comment: Sorry for a noob question, but should I set up somewhat to call that function right after an user sign in the app. Then query the collection status whenever I need.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you're asking.  If you have another question that's not related to the first, I suggest you ask a whole new question on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I mean, in the page that you showed me. They create /status  to store the status ('online' or 'offline') under userID if I'm not mistaken. So I should call the whole above function right after signing in for each user (E.g  click sign in button to send sign in request and add status request). So I have status for every users, right ? If it's still not so clear, I 'll make a new question on Stack Overflow then.

Comment: I think you should ask a new question and clarify what you're doing.